# How to change png file parameter IHDR width using imageshack

Tags: playonlinux, png

I have a image with X*Y size say 42*42 and I want to change the X part to 384 fixed. I have a software which accepts only 384*Y size of images. I can change manually the X to 384 using paint:

1. Open the image in paint.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> a window will open with image properties
3. Change the Width to 384.
4. It adds some white space to that image, so that my original image doesn't gets altered.

My original image:

[image]

The altered picture:

[image]

If you download the image then you can find the difference.

My question is how can I do it using command line?

Comment: Are you using Paint in PlayOnLinux? Why not use Gimp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming your image via the command line can be done fairly easily by using ImageMagick, the *gold standard* application for image manipulation:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

The syntax below converted your image nicely to your requirements:

```
convert original.png -gravity west -background white -extent 384x42 altered.png
```

Below is the *original image* with the *altered image* underneath it. I have set the background for the *altered image* using `-background skyblue`, substituting for `-background white` to make the padding a little easier to see on Ask Ubuntu:

[image]

[image]

ImageMagick is pretty cool :).

**References:**

- [ImageMagick: Extent, Direct Image Size Adjustment](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#extent)

Comment: Thank you @andrew.46 it worked perfectly the way I wanted

Comment: @seereddisekhar It is great news that it all worked well for you :)